# c++ code for ceating X509 certificate and verify it

Tags: ssl

i'm doing a code for server client the server is CA and the client sends signed request to server and the server create signed certificate then the client sends to the server its certificate. The server first verify the certificate. also the client Extract the serial number of the certificate 
i have some problems here 
1- the verify process fail 
verifiy fail
certificate signature failure
2- the serial number is always return a constant number 3 i don't know why

thx allot for helping me

certificate.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "server.h"
#include "client.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
Client clientest;
Server servertest;
X509 *cert;
cert = servertest.CreateCertificate(clientest.MakeSignedCertReq());
clientest.SetCert(cert);
clientest.CertConverter();
X509 *test;
test = clientest.GetCert();
servertest.CheckCert(cert);
int serial = 0;
serial = clientest.ExtractCertSerial();
cout<<"client serial is "<<serial<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

server.h

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl/asn1.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/conf.h>
#include  "client.h"
#include <openssl/x509.h>
#include <openssl/x509_vfy.h>
using namespace std;
class Server
{
 public:
 Server();
 ~Server();
 X509 *CreateCertificate (X509_REQ *req);
 void CreateMyCertificate();
 void GenerateMyKeyPairs ( );
 void SetPublicKey ();
 int CheckCert (X509 *clientcert);
 private:
 X509       *m_myCert;
 RSA        *m_caKeyPairs;
 EVP_PKEY   *m_pukey;
 X509_NAME  *m_issuerName;
 };
 #endif /* SERVER_H_ */
```

server.cc

```
#include "server.h"
Server::Server()
{
  m_myCert = X509_new();
  m_caKeyPairs = RSA_new();
  m_pukey  = EVP_PKEY_new();
  m_issuerName = X509_NAME_new();
  GenerateMyKeyPairs();
  CreateMyCertificate();
  //SetPublicKey();
 }
 Server::~Server()
 {
  X509_free(m_myCert);
  RSA_free(m_caKeyPairs);
  X509_NAME_free(m_issuerName);
  }
  X509*
  Server::CreateCertificate(X509_REQ* req)
  {
     cout<<"hello i began"<<endl;
    X509 *m_req_reply;
    m_req_reply = X509_new();
    X509_NAME *subject = NULL;
    EVP_PKEY *pkey = NULL;
     ASN1_INTEGER_set(X509_get_serialNumber(m_req_reply), 2);
     X509_gmtime_adj(X509_get_notBefore(m_req_reply), 0);
    X509_gmtime_adj(X509_get_notAfter(m_req_reply), 31536000L);
     pkey = X509_REQ_get_pubkey(req);
   X509_set_pubkey(m_req_reply, pkey); 
     X509_NAME *issuerSubject = X509_get_subject_name(m_myCert);
     X509_set_issuer_name(m_req_reply, issuerSubject);
     //extract the subject of the request
    subject = X509_REQ_get_subject_name(req);
    X509_set_subject_name(m_req_reply, subject);
     cout << "cert subject name:" << X509_get_subject_name(m_req_reply) << endl;
     if(1 == X509_sign(m_req_reply, m_pukey, EVP_sha1()))
     cout << "client cert ok\n";
     else
     cout << "client cert error\n";
     return m_req_reply;
     }
  void
  Server::CreateMyCertificate()
  {
 // we use rsa pairs and assign it into evp_key
 SetPublicKey();
 // properties of the certificate
 //set the serial number
 ASN1_INTEGER_set(X509_get_serialNumber(m_myCert), 1);
 //set the time validity
 X509_gmtime_adj(X509_get_notBefore(m_myCert), 0);
 X509_gmtime_adj(X509_get_notAfter(m_myCert), 31536000L);
 //set the public key of the cert to be signed
 X509_set_pubkey(m_myCert, m_pukey);
 //this is a self-signed certificate, we set the name of the issuer to the name of the subject
 m_issuerName = X509_get_subject_name(m_myCert);
 X509_NAME_add_entry_by_txt(m_issuerName, "C",  MBSTRING_ASC,
                            (unsigned char *)"CA", -1, -1, 0);
 X509_NAME_add_entry_by_txt(m_issuerName, "O",  MBSTRING_ASC,
                            (unsigned char *)"MyCompany Inc.", -1, -1, 0);
 X509_NAME_add_entry_by_txt(m_issuerName, "CN", MBSTRING_ASC,
                            (unsigned char *)"localhost", -1, -1, 0);
 //set the issuer name
 X509_set_issuer_name(m_myCert, m_issuerName);
 //sign the cert
 if(1 == X509_sign(m_myCert, m_pukey, EVP_sha1()))
     cout << "self cert signed ok\n";
 else
     cout << "self cert sign error\n";
 FILE * fcert;
 fcert = fopen("cert.pem", "wb");
 PEM_write_X509(
     fcert,   /* write the certificate to the file we've opened */
     m_myCert /* our certificate */
 );
 }
 void
 Server::GenerateMyKeyPairs()
 {
 m_caKeyPairs = RSA_generate_key(2048,RSA_F4 , NULL , NULL);
 }
 void
 Server::SetPublicKey()
 {
 if(1 == EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA(m_pukey,m_caKeyPairs))
     cout << "key assigned OK\n";
 else
     cout << "key assign error\n";
 BIO *out = NULL;
 const char szPath[10] = "key2.pem";
 out = BIO_new_file(szPath,"wb");
 EVP_PKEY_print_private(out, m_pukey,
                                0, NULL);
 BIO_free(out);
 out = BIO_new_file("key.pem","wb");
 //print the self signed certificate
 //FILE * fkey;
 //fkey = fopen("key.pem", "wb");
 PEM_write_bio_PrivateKey(
     out,                  /* write the key to the file we've opened */
     m_pukey,               /* our key from earlier */
     EVP_des_ede3_cbc(), /* default cipher for encrypting the key on disk */
     (unsigned char *)"replace_me",       /* passphrase required for decrypting the key on disk */
     10,                 /* length of the passphrase string */
     NULL,               /* callback for requesting a password */
     NULL                /* data to pass to the callback */
 );
 }
 int
 Server::CheckCert(X509* clientcert)
 {
 int status = 0;
 X509_STORE_CTX *ctx = X509_STORE_CTX_new();
 //void X509_STORE_CTX_cleanup(X509_STORE_CTX *ctx);
 //void X509_STORE_CTX_free(X509_STORE_CTX *ctx);
 //store the trusted cert into ctx
 X509_STORE *store = X509_STORE_new();
 X509_STORE_add_cert(store, m_myCert);
 //put the trusted cert and cert then verify it
 X509_STORE_CTX_init(ctx,store, clientcert, NULL);
 status  = X509_verify_cert(ctx);
 //status = X509_verify(clientcert, m_pukey);
 if (status == 1)
 {
     cout<<"verified succesfully"<<endl;
 }
 else
 {
     cout<<"verifiy fail"<<endl;
     cout << X509_verify_cert_error_string(X509_STORE_CTX_get_error(ctx));
 }
 return status;
 }
```

client.h

```
#ifndef CLIENT_H_
#define CLIENT_H_
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/conf.h>
#include <openssl/x509.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include "server.h"
class Client
{
 public:
Client();
~Client();
void GenerateRSAKeyPair ();
void SetPublicKey ();
X509_REQ *MakeSignedCertReq();
void SetCert (X509 *cert);
X509 *GetCert();
int CertConverter ();
int ExtractCertSerial ();
private:
X509_REQ   *m_myCertReq;
X509       *m_myCert;
X509_NAME  *m_name;
RSA        *m_rsa_keyPair;
EVP_PKEY   *m_puk;
};
#endif /* CLIENT_H_ */
```

client.cc

```
#include "client.h"
Client :: Client()
{
  m_myCertReq = X509_REQ_new();
  m_myCert = X509_new();
  m_name = X509_NAME_new();
  m_rsa_keyPair = RSA_new();
  m_puk  = EVP_PKEY_new();
  GenerateRSAKeyPair();
 // SetPublicKey();
 }
Client :: ~Client()
{
  X509_REQ_free(m_myCertReq);
  X509_free(m_myCert);
  //X509_NAME_free(m_name);
  RSA_free(m_rsa_keyPair);
  //EVP_PKEY_free(m_puk);
 }
void
Client :: GenerateRSAKeyPair ( )
{
 m_rsa_keyPair = RSA_generate_key(2048,RSA_F4,NULL,NULL);
 BIO *pubout = NULL;
 const char szPath[10] = "clrsa.pem";
 pubout = BIO_new_file(szPath,"wb");
 PEM_write_bio_RSAPublicKey (pubout , m_rsa_keyPair);
}
void
Client::SetPublicKey()
{
 EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA(m_puk,m_rsa_keyPair);
 BIO *out = NULL;
 const char szPath[10] = "cpuky.pem";
 out = BIO_new_file(szPath,"wb");
 PEM_write_bio_PUBKEY(out,m_puk);
}
X509_REQ*
Client::MakeSignedCertReq()
{
 SetPublicKey();
 //include the public key in the req
 X509_REQ_set_pubkey(m_myCertReq,m_puk);
 //set the subject name of the request
 m_name=X509_REQ_get_subject_name(m_myCertReq);
 //set the request
 X509_NAME_add_entry_by_txt(m_name,"C",MBSTRING_ASC, (const unsigned char *)"UK", -1, -1, 0);
 X509_NAME_add_entry_by_txt(m_name,"CN",MBSTRING_ASC, (const unsigned char *)"OpenSSL Group", -1, -1, 0);
 //sign the req
 X509_REQ_sign(m_myCertReq,m_puk,EVP_sha1());
 BIO *out = NULL;
 const char szPath[10] = "req.pem";
 out = BIO_new_file(szPath,"wb");
 PEM_write_bio_X509_REQ(out,m_myCertReq);
 return m_myCertReq;
 }
 void
 Client::SetCert(X509 *cert)
 {
 cout << "writing certificate\n";
 BIO *out = NULL;
 const char szPath[10] = "x509.pem";
 out = BIO_new_file(szPath,"wb");
 m_myCert =  cert;
 int len;
 unsigned char *buf, *p;
 len = i2d_X509(cert, NULL);
 cout << "cert length =" << len << endl;
 buf = (unsigned char *)OPENSSL_malloc(len);
 p = buf;
 i2d_X509(cert, &p);
 cout << "cert= "<<endl;
 for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
     cout << buf[i];
 cout << endl;
 if(!PEM_write_bio_X509 (out , cert))
     cout << "error writing certificate\n";
  }
 int
 Client::CertConverter()
 {
 int len = i2d_X509(m_myCert, NULL);
 unsigned char *buf, *p;
 buf = (unsigned char *)OPENSSL_malloc(len);
 p = buf;
 i2d_X509(m_myCert, &p);
 unsigned char certarray[len];
 for (int i = 0 ; i<len ; i++)
 {
     certarray[i] = *(p-len+i);
 }
 cout << "converted client cert is"<<endl;
 for (int j = 0 ; j<len ; j++)
 {
     cout << certarray[j];
 }
 cout<<endl;
 /*
 X509 *certtest = NULL;
 certtest = d2i_X509(NULL, certarray , len);
 cout<<"write the array to file"<<endl;
 FILE * fcert;
 fcert = fopen("certarray.pem", "wb");
 PEM_write_X509(
     fcert,    //write the certificate to the file we've opened
     certtest  //our certificate
 );
*/
 return 0;
 }
 X509*
 Client::GetCert()
 {
 return m_myCert;
 }
 int
 Client::ExtractCertSerial()
 {
 int serial = 0;
 unsigned char **out = NULL;
 ASN1_INTEGER *asn1_serial = NULL;
 asn1_serial = X509_get_serialNumber(m_myCert);
 serial = i2d_ASN1_INTEGER(asn1_serial, out);
 return (serial);
 }
```

hope that any one can help me soon to solve my problem

note i have the self signed cert created well in cert.pem file also the x509.pem (for the client ) is created well but when i verify it i got an error all the time not verified because of the certificate signature failure when i got error handler X509_verify_cert_error_string(X509_STORE_CTX_get_error(ctx)) also the serial number is always constant 3

Answer (score 2):

I found out that in the request should add

```
     //adds all digest algorithms to the table
     OpenSSL_add_all_digests();
```

without this line the certificate will never be verified correctly

Answer (score 0):

1. In `CreateCertificate(X509_REQ* req){...}`, you have
   `ASN1_INTEGER_set(X509_get_serialNumber(m_req_reply), 2);` so you
   will always set the serial number to 2(3).
2. Also in `CreateCertificate(X509_REQ* req){...}`, you have`if(1 == X509_sign(m_req_reply, m_pukey, EVP_sha1()))` but `X509_sign(...)` will return the size of the signature instead of 1 if it succeeds.